# Connecting to samba share through win7 Home(!)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, samba

Ok, I've tried everything. Changing LmCompatibilityLevel , configuring samba on every possible way but still win7 doesn't see my server. When I try to map my drive it wants authentication but It doesn't accept any user (I've even made the same user for unix and win7) .Any ideas where to go next? (btw server is running new ubuntu)

Comment: Take a deep breath. Ok, now that you're calm, please re-read your question. It's half unintelligible and the other half is worthless. Please edit it to include *meaningful* details about the client and the server, post some relevant logs, post your SAMBA configs, etc.

Comment: I gladly would, but the thing is that to post some meaningful logs I need to know which ones are RELEVANT and that's what I'am asking for. I've no idea what more do you want to know about my system. I wrote that the server is new ubuntu server and my client win7 home.

Comment: If you don't even know where to look, then it sounds like you need to read the documentation. Once you have a firm grasp on the technology that you're asking about, you'll be better equipped to come back and ask a meaningful question.

Answer (score 4):

Samba doesn't use the host server's users file. You have to add users to Samba with `smbpasswd`